# CSS Space left and right for border line

Tags: html, css, border, space

have added a separator line into my table. 
Works fine. 
But now I would like to let the line to 
leave space on the left and on the right. 
I have tried border width already,
but it rather made my border thicker than defining its width...

So how can I get space for the line while the text stays on its place?

my HTML:

```
<table class="layoutTable">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table class="philosophyText">
                <tr>
                    <th class="header line">HEADER TEXT</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text_allground">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</tr>
            </table>
```

My CSS:

```
#section2.section .half:last-child .philosophyText {
    width:100%;
    padding-left:18%;
    padding-right:18%;
}

#section2.section .half:last-child .philosophyText th {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 2.3vh;
    padding-top:5.0vh;
    padding-bottom:0.5vh;
    font-weight:100;
}

#section2.section .half:last-child .philosophyText td {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-size: 1.75vh;
    padding-top:2.0vh;
    font-weight:300;
}

#section2.section .half:last-child .philosophyText .line {
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;
    }
```

My current table looks like that:

[image]

Comment: You have a `HTML` markup error...you should close the `<td class="text_allground">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
.layoutTable { border-spacing: 5px; }
```

You can add spacing between cells by using [`border-spacing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing) (like old school `cellspacing` attribute).

One point I would make though is tables are for tabular data, they should never be used for layout (unless writing an email template)

You also haven't closed the `text_allground` `td`

Answer (score 0):

```
table tr td {
 padding: 0px 20px;   
}
```

But I would suggest to not use table for that.
use divs

Answer (score 0):

```
correct your table coding

<table class="layoutTable">
            <tr>
              <td><table class="philosophyText">
                  <tr>
                  <th class="header line"> HEADER TEXT </th>

                </tr>
                  <tr>
                  <td class="text_allground"> 

                      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
```